# Cognito login with tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Our website uses Cognito to login and storing necessary user data. It includes of API Gateway with lambdas that are authorized with Cognito User Pool.

Our client wants to login to our website with a token, that has user's email stored within. With that email we can retrieve the most recent refresh token that user has used (it's stored in the RDS).
With that refresh token I can do adminInitiateAuth in lambda and retrieve
new access and id tokens.

How can I use these to login to Cognito? Is it possible? Or do I just insert the received id token to every API call?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito User Pool is responsible for generating those tokens after successfully completing the authentication flow, that's the actual "login to Cognito".

Once you receive the ID and Access tokens you should use [one of] them to access the needed resources (eg, API Gateway) for each API call, by using it in some configured header or other defined mean.

In your case, seems you have already performed the *initial* authentication (when you got the refresh token) and are performing a token refresh where you'll still receive the ID and Access token but not a new refresh token.

Keep in mind that the refresh token also has an expiration (defaulting to 30 days, up to 10 years), so at some point you may need to re-perform initial authentication to get new one.

Here's AWS documentation on [Using tokens with user pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) and [Control access to a REST API using Amazon Cognito user pools as authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html).

Comment: Thank you. So it works like I started to implement it (including new tokens in every API call). Yes, I need to forward users to normal login page after expiration is done. And I need to figure out how to get that new refresh token when user logs in, to store it RDS.

Comment: Depending on the auth flow you are using, you can have an endpoint/service in the middle performing the authentication: `client <-> endpoint/service <-> cognito` and the cognito response with the tokens will be sent to the service, which can store it in RDS.
Another option is to have the App Client callback URL to a similar endpoint/service that will receive the tokens, store them in RDS and forward the user to the proper URL after.